# Insert select In ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I tried to write the following  Insert  select  query with  LEFT JOIN using an Oracle database:

```
 insert  into tables  (TABLE_NAME,DATA_LENGTH,NUM_ROWS) 
 SELECT user_tables.TABLE_NAME
         ,SUM(ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.DATA_LENGTH)
        ,user_tables.NUM_ROWS 
  FROM user_tables 
  LEFT JOIN ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
      ON user_tables.TABLE_NAME = ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME 
  WHERE OWNER= 'SYSTEM' 
  AND (user_tables.TABLE_NAME ='TIMELEVEL' 
      OR user_tables.TABLE_NAME ='CHANLEVEL'
      OR user_tables.TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTLEVEL' 
     OR user_tables.TABLE_NAME = 'PRODLEVEL'
     OR user_tables.TABLE_NAME = 'ACTVARS' ) 
 GROUP BY user_tables.TABLE_NAME ;
```

That gives the below error:

```
ORA-00904 : "NUM_ROWS" : invalid identifier
```

The DDL of one table is:

```
CREATE  TABLE  tables (name_tables VARCHAR2(60)
      ,tuple VARCHAR2(50),
       taille_tuple VARCHAR2(50))
```

Comment: what's the difference between an Oracle database or mysql? you have it tagged both

Comment: Your table creation statement shows it doesn't have a column called `num_rows`. Or either of the other column names in your `insert`. Have you just misunderstood the insert syntax?

Comment: Just had a DOH moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the INSERT part of the statement:

```
insert  into tables  (TABLE_NAME,DATA_LENGTH,NUM_ROWS)
```

The clause in parentheses specifies the target columns in the inserted table. Your version uses names from columns in the queried tables, which are different from the columns in `tables`. This clause is optional: we only need to specify the target columns when we're not populating all the columns. But if it's there, the names need to match, so

```
insert  into tables  (name_tables,tuple,taille_tuple)
```

Comment: with that hat on you look like a line from a Billy Joel song: "You had the Dom Perignon in your hand and the moon up your nose"... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis - now I'm "we didn't start the fire" :)